# How to define const getters for djinni?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, constants, djinni

I define a C++ interface with *djinni*:

```
member = interface +c {
    get_id(): string;
    get_name(): string;
}
```

My inherited implementation uses const getters, i.e.

```
class MyMemeber: public Member {
  private:
    string id;
    string name;
  public:
    string get_id() const override { return id; }
    string get_name() const override { return name; }
}
```

This obviously fails to compile, because of `const` attribute. Can I teach *djinni* to generate the base interface with const getters, too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is nowhere documented though from the very beginning djinni generates const methods [(line 295 of src/source/CppGenerator.scala)](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/commit/b5bacd702e878c2a1cb0b474410190d82207c135). Just add const in front of method signature in idl file:

```
member = interface +c {
    const get_id(): string;
    const get_name(): string;
}
```

I think it would be good idea to pull request tests for this feature (and some docs), [currently only const fields are tested](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/blob/master/test-suite/djinni/constants.djinni).

Comment: Fascinating.  I'm the primary maintainer of Djinni these days, and I didn't know about this feature, and even had it on a wish-list/backlog.  It's only minimally useful since constness is meaningless to Java and ObjC, and all interface arguments are passed by pointer-to-non-const.  Ideally what I'd really like is proper const-correctness, which would require const interface arguments, and some sort of enforcement in other languages.  I'll add a const method to the test suite, at least, to demonstrate that it exists.

Comment: @atwyman I was also surprised, thought that there is no such feature but wanted to verify it in source generator and voila! (-; Someone should verify if we don't have more stuff like this. (-;

Comment: I am glad I didn't start with the source code: it would result in me using this feature which never was properly tested, while nobody else knows that it exists!

Comment: I added a test and it works fine.  I also added some docs to the README.  Both should land on github this week.

Comment: @AlexCohn I hope i did not mislead you. I think that my answer will require update when atwyman will push changes to git. Do you require any other updates in order to accept this answer?

Comment: Thank you **@atwyman** and **mkk** this was a great example of best advantages of Stack Overflow, the best in my experience.